# WebGL : data to non square alpha texture

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures

I have a weird problem with webGL.

I'm using a dynamically generated texture of which only the alpha channel matters.
Here's the code:

```
var texture  = new Uint8Array(ar); // ar is my array
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.transparencyTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, array.length, array[0].length, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I'm always using a POT array' "width" and "height" but whenever "width" <> "height" it doesn't work. So it currently only works with squares.

What can be done?

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/SergeJcqmn/EAmjU/9/

Comment: Seems like a browser bug, but it's hard to know without more details.   For example, what are your texture coordinates?  What do you get from `gl.getError()`?  How does it appear visually?

Comment: Just curious but `array.length, array[0].length` ? So you have a 2 dimensional array in JavaScript? How does that relate to `ar`?

Comment: I provide correct coordinates (used for other textures as well). gl.getError() returns 0. it displays only as vec4(0, 0, 0, 0) pixels/fragments.

Comment: I generate ar from a 2 dimensional array correctly. I checked ar length and it's equal to array.length * array[0].length. And even if I was generating it wrong (which I don't) it would result in something else than a 100% vec4(0, 0, 0, 0) texture. Plus when I use a "square" texture, the results is just fine.

Comment: Here's a demo : http://serge.snakeman.be/Demo/Portail.html the upper bar (some sort of energy bar) should be filled by a random amount of blue each frame (And yet, it's plain black due to the problem I have).

Comment: @Serge  Make a jsfiddle.net with a working snippet of your code. It will help people answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jsfiddle, line 76 of the js is incorrect:

```
ar.push(array[x][(array.length - 1) - y] ?  128 : 0);
```

I believe this should be:

```
ar.push(array[x][(array[0].length - 1) - y] ?  128 : 0);
```

Comment: You're perfectly right. I'm suprised no "out of index" error were repported (since that was the mistake). Thank you.